# Audio is not in sync with images using Viewpager

Tags: image, audio, android-viewpager, synchronization

I am creating a simple android app. i used the code all images and sound etc works fine but audio is not in pattern(sync) according to my images.
According to sound image is one step next means for example for ant the bee sound plays and i want to play ant sound for ant and bee for fee
I am using the same array index of images and audios but nothing works.
here is my code MainActivity.java

```
    package com.example.zeeshanm.ibrahim;

  import android.media.MediaPlayer;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.content.Context;
  import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
  import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  public MediaPlayer mp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.myfivepanelpager);
    ImagePagerAdapter adapter = new ImagePagerAdapter();
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}


private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {



    private int[] mImages = new int[] {R.drawable.ant,R.drawable.bee,
            R.drawable.cat,R.drawable.dog,R.drawable.duck,R.drawable.elephant,
            R.drawable.frog,R.drawable.giraffe,R.drawable.horse,R.drawable.iguana,R.drawable.jaguar,R.drawable.koala,
            R.drawable.lion,R.drawable.monkey,R.drawable.numbat,R.drawable.owl,R.drawable.panda,R.drawable.parrot,
            R.drawable.quoll,R.drawable.rabbit,R.drawable.seal,R.drawable.snack,R.drawable.tiger,R.drawable.uracca,
            R.drawable.vampirebat,R.drawable.wombat,R.drawable.xenops,R.drawable.yacare,R.drawable.zebra};


    private int[] mAudio= new int[]{R.raw.hormiga_ant_en,R.raw.abeja_bee_en,R.raw.shout_jaguar,
            R.raw.shout_perro_dog,R.raw.pato_duck_en,
            R.raw.elefante_elephant_en,R.raw.shout_rana_frog,R.raw.jirafa_giraffe_en,
            R.raw.shout_caballo_horse,R.raw.iguana_en,R.raw.jaguar_en,R.raw.shout_koala,R.raw.leon_lion_en,
            R.raw.shout_mono_monkey,
            R.raw.numbat_en,R.raw.shout_buho_owl,R.raw.shout_oso_bear,
            R.raw.shout_zorro_fox,R.raw.quoll_en,R.raw.conejo_rabbit_en,R.raw.shout_foca_seal,
            R.raw.shout_serpiente_snake,
            R.raw.tigre_tiger_en,R.raw.shout_urraca,R.raw.murcielago_vampirebat_en,
            R.raw.shout_murcielago_vampirebat,R.raw.xenops_en,R.raw.shout_yacare,R.raw.shout_cebra_zebra};






    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mImages.length;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((ImageView) object);
    }
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        Context context = MainActivity.this;
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

        int padding =context.getResources().
                getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.activity_vertical_margin);
        imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);



          //for Sound
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();

        }



        mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, mAudio[position]);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Position is " + mAudio[position] + "  and  " + mImages[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        mp.start();




        return imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((ImageView) object);
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be a bit more specific. "Does not work" means what?

Comment: Thanks for reply and does not work means that the audio is not sync with images . so how to do it ?

Comment: How to sync audio with the images. That when the first image comes on screen then the first audio is played and when second image is displayed then second audio is played and so on.

Comment: It would seem to me, that MediaPlayer can play only one media at once, and just queues your further requests: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Yes but i want to play one sound at once, not more than one but when i swype it should be different. Sir i tell you that this code is working and the images starts correctly but the audio is different. Is the any way to fix this problem ?